# mongoclient no method loadServerScripts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a javascript function `echoFunction();` stored on a compose.io mongo server. From the shell I can successfully run the function after running `db.loadServerScripts();` because running `db.eval( "echoFunction( 'test' )" )` gives me a unauthorized error. My question is how can I run these from within nodejs using MongoClient. From node I get the following error.

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'loadServerScripts'

Here is my code.

```
app.post('/import', function(req, res) {
    res.send(200, "OK ");
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://username:password@compose.io.com/db', function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        db.collection('collection').insert(req.body, {
            w: 1
        }, function(err, objects) {
            db.loadServerScripts("system.js");
            db.echoFunction();
            if (err) console.warn(err.message);
            if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
                // this _id was already inserted in the database
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Will compose.io let you run server-side javascript? You said you get an unauthorized error in the shell - I'm guessing they won't let you run it. I wouldn't run it in a hosted mongoDB.

Comment: No they don't allow server-side JavaScript, which is why I'm trying to figure out another solution.

Comment: What you're trying to do here is run server-side javascript.